# Why does LaTeX forget commands when their code is between two \\ signs?

Tags: macros

I have the following problem. When trying to compile the code

```
\newcommand{\system}{$\displaystyle \left\{
\begin{aligned}
&y=0\\
&y^2=0\\
\end{aligned} \right.$}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \newcommand{\sameas}{\\ \rotatebox{90}{$\Leftrightarrow$} \\}
    $\displaystyle y=0$
    \sameas
    $\displaystyle y^2=0$
    \sameas
    \system
    \sameas
    \system
    \sameas
    $\displaystyle y=0$
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

LaTeX displays the first call to `\sameas` correctly, but says it doesn't know what `\sameas` is in the following calls. Why does it suddenly forget the definition of `\sameas`?

Here's the error message:

```
l.94     \sameas
                
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I'm using Overleaf.

Comment: Welcome! Please add the necessary code (preamble, etc) so that we can compile your code: help us to help you!

Comment: Inside a `tabular` every cell is an implicit group, and TeX forgets local assignments at the end of a group.

Comment: If you just move your definition of `\sameas` one line up it'll still not affect the rest of your document (it'll be local to `center`), but your `tabular` will work out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A table or alignment cell  is a *tex group*, so

```
.... & \newcommand\foo{???}  &   \foo
```

is like

```
.... { \newcommand\foo{???}  }   \foo
```

and all non global assignments are discarded at a group end.

Comment: Maybe add the note that if the command is moved outside the `tabular` but inside the `center` environment it'll still not leak but affect all the cells?

Comment: Also, 4 seconds too slow! :)